# Accessible submit button with background image

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I have a form submit button, using  that has a background image containing a 'pretty' styled version of the 'value' text.

I was hiding the html value text using:

```
text-indent: -9000px;
font-size: 0;
```

However, with image turned off (for accessibility testing) there is obviously no button text displayed.

Removing the above brings the value text back, but it overlays on top of the image.

How can I have the background image on top of the value text?

By first guess is some combination of `<button><span></span></button>` ?

Comment: What's the use case for no images? A screen reader? If this is the case, then text-indent'd text will still get read.

Comment: Hmm. If you're worried about accessibility, are you sure this is the right route to go in the first place? Wouldn't placing the explanatory text outside the button be easier?

Comment: @Pekka, sorry question wasn't completely clear - it's not explanatory text, its the text the value would display otherwise - changed the question to reflect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about using an img tag inside the button, and giving that an alt attribute:

HTML:

```
<button class="button">
 <img src="http://www.google.nl/logos/2010/stnicday10-infstant.jpg" alt="google"/>
</button>
```

CSS:

```
.button {
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid Black;
}
```

Comment: P.S. remove the "f" in the google URL to see the image instead of the alt text: 'infstant' becomes 'instant'

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this: `<button>Your BTN Text<span class="img">&nbsp;</span></button>`

and in CSS:

```
button { position: relative;}
button span {
  position: absolute;
  text-indent: -9000px;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background: url(yourimage.whatever);
}
```

so if us disable the images the text is still visible under the absolute element.

Answer (score 0):

Make as `value=""` (empty):

```
<input type='submit' name="csubmit" value="" />
```

If you have multiple <kbd>submit</kbd> buttons and validating based on button clicked leave value with empty space:

```
<input type-"submit" name="csubmit1" value=" " />
<input type-"submit" name="csubmit2" value=" " />
<input type-"submit" name="csubmit3" value=" " />
```

Answer (score -2):

Set the button's value to empty:

```
<input type="submit" value="" />
```

and you can remove the `text-indent` from your CSS.

This will obviously display no text whatsoever, but when you disable the CSS background, the button will still be visible.

Comment: You can't have a background image with text AND the button value beneath it with only HTML and CSS. Either you go with no value or change the background to contain no text and style the submit button's text.